# What is the reason for this 'linear "error"'

Tags: filter-design, lowpass-filter

Here's **MIM** (*Magnitude Invariance Method*) [thesis](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Mapping-Controllers-from-the-S-domain-to-the-Z-dom-Vadhavkar/26e8e72f66147e14a3adea23961efd5c0fa42765) (press the "View PDF" to get the theis with MATLAB code in hands) and here's a plot showing the issue I'm trying to solve:

[image]

*Magnitude responses for one pole LP filter at few frequency locations.*

As plot shows, there's some sort of an issue in MIM function **c2dn()** implementation, which 'moves' the *fc* point especially at low *fc* values. *IIRC, same type of error happens when changing the *fs*.*

Analog prototype LPF is calculated as:

```
w0 = 2*pi*fc;
Analogb = 1;
Analoga = [1 w0];
Analog = tf(Analogb, Analoga);
Analog = Analog/dcgain(Analog);
```

which is then given as an input for to calculate the MIM filter:

```
fs=44100;
mimpim = 'mim';
samplingtime = 1/fs;
numofsamples = 2048;
[Dz1] = c2dn(Analog, samplingtime, mimpim, 1, numofsamples);
%[a, b, T] = tfdata(Dz1);   %coeffs
```

where **c2dn()** is the function from MIM paper.

Plotting:

```
fs2 = fs/2;
nf = logspace(0, 5, fs2);
[mag, pha] = bode(Analog,2*pi*nf);
semilogx(nf, 20*log10(abs(mag)), 'color', 'g', 'linewidth', 1.5);
axis([10 fs2 -50 1]);
hold on;[mag, pha] = bode(Dz1,2*pi*nf);
semilogx(nf, 20*log10(abs(mag)), 'color', 'k', 'linewidth', 1.5, 'linestyle', '--');grid on;
title('Various TF (LPF 1)');
legend('Analog', 'MIM','location', 'southwest');
xlabel('Hz');ylabel('dB');
```

So far, I've found out that the *fc* error is quite linear (I picked -3dB points for few *fc* and then calculated the trend *f(x)* (R² was 0.99989...)) so, one could probably find the source for "error" by just looking the matlab codes for MIM function **c2dn()**.

Here's plot showing the effect of my correction *f(x)*:

[image]

Correction formula `f(x) = 0.9704384746x - 51.6991952722` works well for *fc* in range 60Hz-Nyqvist (fs=44.1kHz) and can even be improved a bit. (*Note: correction for fc=10Hz showen in plot  is done using another formula so you can omit it as a result of this f(x)*).

Any suggestions regarding the source for this "error" ?

**EDIT:** I quess the functionality behind the issue can be located to cepstral processing block ... there's a line with remark: "*% minimum phase sequence r^mn*" where **h** is recalculated using **lmn** matrix created earlier in "homomorphic filtering" block:

```
h = h.*lmn';
```

When this line is turned to a comment, magnitude plots looks good for any *fc* (if the numofsamples parameter has suitable (big) value):

[image]

Problem is that commenting the line leads to the aliasing issue which is common for this type of filter... :( .

Any thoughts if this (homomorphic filtering/cepstral processing) can somehow be improved to result the *fc* point untouched?

EDIT2:

When the resulting LPF order is 3 or more this issue in discussion is not present anymore:

[image]
(*numofsamples=4096, fs=44.1kHz, fc=1...N Hz*)

--> could it just be so that the fitting method used there in function **c2dn()** isn't suitable for low order filter?